# Getting distinct count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

- companies
- customers for those companies
- addresses for each customer

I want to know how many companies in my database has the accounts with more that 100 addresses linked to them.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.Id) 
FROM 
    Customers cu
INNER JOIN 
    Addresses ad ON ad.Customer = cu.Id
INNER JOIN 
    Companies c ON cu.company = c.Id
GROUP BY 
    cu.ID
HAVING 
    COUNT(ad.ID) > 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two levels of aggregation for this query.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT cu.company, COUNT(DISTINCT ad.id) as num_accresses
      FROM Customers cu 
         INNER JOIN Addresses ad ON ad.Customer = cu.Id
      GROUP BY cu.company
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ad.id) > 100
     ) cua;
```

The inner query returns the companies that have more than 100 addresses.  Note the use of `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  Presumably, two "customers" could have the same addresses.

Also, the companies table is not needed.  The identifying information is in `customers`.  You are only looking for a count, so the table is not necessary.